# ERROR: This solver is not able to use mass matrices

Tags: julia

I am new in Julia language. I have a a large system of ODEs (around 500). When I use the AutoTsit5(Rosenbrock23()) solver, I receive this error:

```
This solver is not able to use mass matrices.
```

Does it mean that I have to use solvers for DAE problems? What other options exist?

Thanks!

I tried different solvers. Some work, some not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does it mean that I have to use solvers for DAE problems? What other options exist?

If you are using a solver to solve an ODEProblem in mass matrix form, you must use one of the methods that's documented as capable of doing this. This is shown in the [DAE solver page](https://docs.sciml.ai/DiffEqDocs/stable/solvers/dae_solve/#OrdinaryDiffEq.jl-(Mass-Matrix)). `AutoTsit5` is not a compatible method with this as no explicit method is compatible with mass matrices (for clear mathematical reasons). `FBDF` would likely be recommended in a scenario like this.

In general, we would highly recommend not choosing an ODE solver and instead relying on the default given by DifferentialEquations.jl's default algorithm unless you have a clear idea of why you're choosing a specific solver.